# Compilation error with a unit test

Tags: unit-test

I'm trying to write a unit test for my Timeline apex class but I keep getting an error: "Compilation error: Constructor not defined:[Timeline].<Constructor>".

```
@isTest
public class TimelineTest {
    public static testMethod void testTimeline() {      
        Test.startTest();

        Participant__c participant = new Participant__c();
        participant.First_Name__c = 'test';
        participant.Last_Name__c = 'user';
        participant.Client_Id__c = '1101';
        participant.DOB__c =  Date.newInstance(1976,1,1);
        insert participant;

        Timeline t = new Timeline();
        t.pid = participant.Id;
        t.violations;

        Test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

My Timeline class looks like this:

```
public class Timeline {
    public String pid {get;set;}
    public Timeline(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        pid = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id');
        violations = JSON.serialize( Database.query('SELECT...') );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the constructor `Timeline()` is not defined. Therefore you can ether implement the method `Timeline()` in your Class Timeline or you can use the already defined constructor.

Create a standard controller / set the url parameter:

```
Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().put('Id', participant.id);
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(participant);

//initalize timeline
Timeline t = new Timeline(sc);
```

Comment: I added my Timeline class to the question. Can you take a look at it again? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I added your code and I got a similar error. Then I changed
ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(participant.id); 
to 

ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.standardController(participant);
I think it works now. At least no errors.

Comment: If Christian's response answered your question, click to vote it up and accept it as the solution.